# How to fix "StringConverter cannot convert from System.Double." in In\\UiPath

Tags: excel, uipath

When I make the "Read Cell" in "Excel application scope", I tried to output the read data from Excel by using "Write Line". However, It's not working and it ouput the error as in the Title. Could you someone make it up?

Comment: Please include the code you are using that generates this error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help.

Comment: I couldn't the error code..

Comment: Did you try `yourString.toString`?

Comment: Yes, I did. but i finally make it by using "GenericValue" in variable type.

Comment: ^^^^ "Object" works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'm using the **LookupDataTable** activity. In my Excel file I have a mix of Strings and Integers. But somehow I also got the error:

> NotSupportedException: StringConverter cannot convert from
>   System.Double.

I solved it by changing the variable from **String** to **GenericValue**.

I also tried to give it the Double type, but it didn't work because I think I have different types in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe be it will help you to check out
Convert.todouble

Comment: That's not a proper way. A better solution would be to change the type of the variable directly instead of changing the type.